# Install log file is missing

Tags: logging, inno-setup

I made a script including this:

```
[Setup]

SetupLogging=yes
```

But I can't find the log file. It seems like it was not created. 
Where could it be?

Is that possible to specify where I want to place it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify a path to the log file by the setup [`/LOG="filename"`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=LOG2) command line parameter. So to log e.g. to the `C:\FileName.log` file run your setup this way:

```
Setup.exe /LOG="C:\FileName.log"
```

If you don't specify the above command line parameter, the log will be saved to the temporary directory into the file with the following name pattern:

```
Setup Log YYYY-MM-DD #NNN.txt
```

Where:

```
YYYY - current system time year
MM - current system time month
DD - current system time day
NNN - number unique for each day starting from 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I specify where to place the log from the script itself? I prefer not to ask the users to use "/LOG"

Comment: I've read the above information from source code. No, there is no such option. The only place where the `LogFilename` variable is filled [`is here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Main.pas#L2780). Then [`it's checked`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Main.pas#L2942) if it's value is empty (that's when the `/LOG="filename"` cmd line parameter is not specified) or not. Depending on that is created log file by the above rules. You can only get the log file name from the [`{log}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#log) constant.

Comment: Windows has several locations for storing temp files, but as @Jason points out in a comment on another answer, Inno uses C:\Users\<User's name>\AppData\Local\Temp, also known as %temp%.

Comment: If you doesn't specify the /Log="filePathToStore" option then it will create log file at `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp` . you will find file named something like `Setup Log 2014-12-10 #001.txt`

Answer (score 11):

It's like TLama describes, if you don't state the logfile's destination as a command line parameter then it will land up in the temp folder. Below is some code that I use for copying the logfile at the DeinitializSetup event for Installer and for the Uninstaller's DeinitializUninstall event.

**Installer**

After instalation the logfile is copied from the temp folder and placed it into one of choice. It handles some cases of pre-mature termination.

```
function MoveLogfileToLogDir():boolean;
var
  logfilepathname, logfilename, newfilepathname: string;
begin
  logfilepathname := expandconstant('{log}');

  //If logfile is disabled then logfilepathname is empty
  if logfilepathname = '' then begin
     result := false;
     exit;
  end;

  logfilename := ExtractFileName(logfilepathname);
  try
    //Get the install path by first checking for existing installation thereafter by GUI settings
    if IsAppInstalled then
       newfilepathname := GetInstalledPath + 'Log\Installer\'
    else
       newfilepathname := expandconstant('{app}\Log\Installer\');
  except
    //This exception is raised if {app} is invalid i.e. if canceled is pressed on the Welcome page
        try
          newfilepathname := WizardDirValue + '\Log\Installer\'; 
        except
          //This exception is raised if WizardDirValue i s invalid i.e. if canceled is pressed on the Mutex check message dialog.
          result := false;
        end;
  end;  
  result := ForceDirectories(newfilepathname); //Make sure the destination path exists.
  newfilepathname := newfilepathname + logfilename; //Add filename

  //if copy successful then delete logfilepathname 
  result := filecopy(logfilepathname, newfilepathname, false);

  if result then
     result := DeleteFile(logfilepathname);
end;

//Called just before Setup terminates. Note that this function is called even if the user exits Setup before anything is installed.
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  MoveLogfileToLogDir;
end;
```

**Uninstaller**

Logging in the Uninstaller is activated by passing "/Log" command line parameter to uninstall.exe. Append this to uninstaller's path in the registry. Cavet: this method will only work if uninstalled from Control Panel (i.e. it won't work if uninstall.exe is excecuted directly)

```
function EnableUninstallerLogging():boolean;
var Key : string;          //Registry path to details about the current installation (uninstall info)
    Value : string;
begin

  //If logfile is disabled then logfilepathname is empty
  if expandconstant('{log}') = '' then begin
     result := false;
     exit;
  end;

  Key := GetAppUninstallRegKey;
  Value := 'UninstallString';
  if RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key, Value) then
     result := RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key, Value, ExpandConstant('"{uninstallexe}" /Log'));
end;


procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
   case CurStep of
         ssInstall : ;
     ssPostInstall : begin
                       //Enable logging during uninstall by adding command line parameter "/Log" to the uninstaller's  reg-path 
                       EnableUninstallerLogging;
                     end;
            ssDone : ;
  end;
end;

//Called just before Uninstaller terminates.
procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
  MoveLogfileToLogDir;
end;
```

**Generic Functions**

Some common functions I use in the sample code above:

```
function GetAppID():string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('{#SetupSetting("AppID")}');     
end;

function GetAppUninstallRegKey():string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + GetAppID + '_is1'); //Get the Uninstall search path from the Registry
end;

function IsAppInstalled():boolean;
var Key : string;          //Registry path to details about the current installation (uninstall info)
begin                            
  Key := GetAppUninstallRegKey;
  result := RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key, 'UninstallString');
end;

//Return the install path used by the existing installation.
function GetInstalledPath():string;
var Key : string;
begin
  Key := GetAppUninstallRegKey;
  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key, 'InstallLocation', result);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had difficulties finding the file! It was in C:\Users\<User's name>\AppData\Local\Temp.