# Inno setup: create a log of selected items

Tags: inno-setup

I'd like to know how to create a log of the selected components at the setup.

I've surfed the net to find it but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print out which components the user selected you'll need to iterate the `ComponentsList` check list box, check if the item is in checked state and if so, print its attribute, most probably `ItemCaption`. The following script shows how to log the selected components as a simple list:

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    Log('Selected components:');

    for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
      if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] then
        Log('Component: ' + WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[I]);
  end;
end;
```

And a screenshot of an Inno Setup component script example log in IDE:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there is any way to save it in a txt file?

Comment: Sure, there is. But before we continue, what is the aim of this log ? Is it used to be just for logging selected components ? And will it be used only for reading, or will you process the stored result somehow ? I mean, is it enough if the output will be in the form that you can see ?

Comment: The aim is to help people having problems when installing so I need to know what they selected.

Comment: Well, so wouldn't then be better for you to get the overall installation log (the same log as you can see on the above screenshot) ? If so, then more about this topic you can find e.g. in [`this thread`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21301731/960757).

Comment: I already have that option, the thing is that I wanted to have this option too.

Comment: If you don't mind I would keep my post as it is (just tweaked the event where it's logged), because you've asked how to log selected components, and that's what that code does. Here is [`the version`](http://pastebin.com/ZNJgG19X) which saves the same lines as marked in the above screenshot into the `MySetupComponents.log` file in user's documents folder.